# How do I create a pair of longitude and latitudes to show a 2 mile radius of a particular longitude and latitude? in Java Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, latitude-longitude

Out of my depth a little :-) How do I create a pair of longitude and latitudes to create a polygon showing a 2 mile radius of a particular longitude and latitude? in Java Android. I know how to find your current longitude and latitude but I just can't figure out the above.

My code so far is below:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

Comment: Not an Android person, but in Java Swing, you'd create a Circle with the center specified and the radius of two miles. If Android does not have circles, that's a bummer, you'd have to create one from lines (a polygon like you said), that's basic trigonometry: use polar coordinate system, xcenter + r * cost (fi), ycenter + r * sin fi. Hope you don't have to resort to that!

Comment: Also, if all you need to do is to figure out whether a specific point is within a certain radius of your coordinates, you go like this: if ((x - x0) * (x - x0) + (y - y0) * (y - y0) < radius * radius)) youAreWithinCircle();

Answer (score 0):

You can create the pair using LatLng.

```
        LatLng origin = new LatLng(my_latitude,my_longitude);
```

For creating a radius you can use Genofencing technique.

https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Comment: Could you explain that a little further?